# Construction of outer automorphisms of GL(n,K)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

If one has an automorphism $\sigma$ of a field $K$, then one can contruct an automorphism $\phi$ of $GL(n,K)$ by applying $\sigma$ to the entries of matrices in $GL(n,K)$. My question is this: if $\sigma$ is nontrivial, then is $\phi$ necessarily an outer automorphism of $GL(n,K)$? Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The scalar matrices $aI, a \in K$ are in the center of $GL(n,K)$ (in fact this describes all elements of the center), so any inner automorphism fixes any such element. But if $\sigma(a) \ne a$ then $\phi(aI) = \sigma(a)I \ne aI$, so $\phi$ can't be inner.

Comment: Good answer. Are there examples of outer automorphisms not constructed this way?

Comment: If $K$ is a prime field, i.e. has no automorphisms, then any outer automorphism if $GL(n,K)$ gives an example. The automorphism $A \mapsto (A^T)^{-1}$ seems like it would work if $\operatorname{char} K \ne 2,3$.