# On an automorphism of general linear group

Tags: group-theory

Let $\tau\neq 1$ be an automorphism of a field $F$ and $\tau_1$ an automorphism of ${\rm GL}_n(F)$ induced by $\tau$ by applying to each entry of the matrix. Then, is $\tau_1$ always a non-inner automorphism?

This may be well known or standard, but if it is so, please provide a reference (or a hint).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Construction of outer automorphisms of GL(n,K)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946910/construction-of-outer-automorphisms-of-gln-k)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of an element $g$ of ${\rm GL}_n(F)$ under an inner automorphism has the same characteristic polynomial and hence the same eigenvalues as $g$. But applying $\tau$ to the entries of $g$ replaces its eigenvalues by their images under $\tau$.

So choose $g$ to be an element having a single eigenvalue, which is not fixed by $\tau$.

Comment: Alternatively: An inner automorphism will fix the center point-wise, while one coming from a field automorphism will not.

Comment: very clear answer! thanks Derek.